# Как воспользоваться стобцом для уникальной цели если он определен как идентификатор

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Привет всем.
Столкнулся с необычной проблемой.
у меня есть БД, столбец COUPON_ID определен с помощью идентификатора, и увеличивается каждый раз на 1.
Пример таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE Coupon
(
    COUPON_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    TITLE VARCHAR(30),
    START_DATE DATE,
    END_DATE DATE,
    AMOUNT INTEGER,
    TYPE VARCHAR(20),
    MESSAGE VARCHAR(300),
    PRICE DOUBLE,
    IMAGE VARCHAR(500),
    CONSTRAINT PRIME_COUPON_ID PRIMARY KEY(COUPON_ID)
);
```

Допустим, я ввeл новые данные, изменял или удалял..., и все работает ОК. И вот возник вопрос при удалении.
Если у меня есть некое кол-во строк, допустим 1000 которые и я намереваюсь удалить. Все нормально удаляется и все нормально продолжает работать. Но вот вопрос, что мне делать потом с этими пустыми строками ?
 Если я захочу в них что-то вставить, то Дерби отказывает, так как пометил id-шник столбца COUPON_ID как идентифицированный столбец и он увеличивается шаг за шагом.
А мне бы хотелось чтобы пустые промежутки строк не накапливались. Есть решение этой проблеме ?

Answer (score 4):

> Столкнулся с необычной проблемой

На самом деле очень часто спрашивают подобные вопросы. На ruSO аналогов не нашёл, поэтому отвечаю.

С чего вы взяли что это проблема?
Ну есть пропуски и что?

Вы не указали СУБД, судя по синтаксису это `Oracle`.

В `Oracle` максимальное значение `BIGINT` = 9223372036854775807.
Допустим в вашей системе вставляется 1 000 000 строк в секунду.
Вычислим через сколько дней тип данных `BIGINT` переполнится.

9223372036854775807/60/60/24 ~ 213 503 982 дней

что составляет примерно 584 942 с половиной года.

Ни вы, ни ваши правнуки, ни железо на ваших серверах не доживёт до события переполнения поля `id`.

Есть способы вставлять данные в пропуски, отключением автоинкремента(по крайней мере в MS SQL). Но в вашем случае это ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать `AUTO_INCREMENT`

значение `AUTO_INCREMENT` будет использоваться повторно, если в какой-либо группе удаляется строка, содержащая наибольшее значение `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Последнее значение поля AUTO_INCREMENT, которое было создано автоматически, можно получить при помощи функции `SQL LAST_INSERT_ID()` или функции API `mysql_insert_id()`.

Взято из [этой статьи](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html)

Comment: а при чем тут mysql?

Comment: @pegoopik автор не уточнил какая база, впрочем, как ты и сказал.  но сути не сильно меняет)